# Html report is not generating for selenium Test case not even blank report

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried a simple selenium program to generate the HTML report. The test case run perfectly but the HTML report is not generating.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
import HtmlTestRunner

# Keyword
url = 'https://amazon.in'
path = 'C:/bin/chromedriver.exe'


class amazonTest(unittest.TestCase):

  @classmethod
   def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
    cls.driver.maximize_window()

   def test_openWebsite(self):
     self.driver.get(url)
     print(self.driver.title)

  @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
     cls.driver.close()
     cls.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output="C:/Users/tester/Desktop/PYTHON/sampleReport"))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Python HTMLTestRunner report output is blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603004/selenium-python-htmltestrunner-report-output-is-blank)

Comment: Nope, it's not even generating a blank report.

Comment: How about this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008312/selenium-python-htmltestrunner-report-is-not-being-generated?

Comment: Can you check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954381/python-htmltestrunner-not-generating-report